# WTForms display foreignkey fields' name in dropdown

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2, wtforms

I am using appengine webapp2 as wsgihandler, jinja2 as the template engine and wtforms as the form module for its support to app engine models.

Following is my simple model:

```
class TaskCategory(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()


class TaskList(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(TaskCategory)
    start_date = db.DateProperty()
    target_finish_date = db.DateProperty()
```

Inside my handlers i write stuff as follows:

```
from wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form

model_dict = {'category': TaskCategory,
          'task': TaskList}

class CreateForm(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, slug):
        form = model_form(model_dict[slug]) # slug can either be category or task.
        self.render_template('index.html', {'form': form()})
```

Following is my template:

```
<form method="POST" action""> 
  <table>
  {% for field in form %}   

    <tr>{{ field.label }}</tr>
    <tr>{{ field()|safe }}</tr>

  <tr>
    {% if field.errors %}
    <td>
      <ul class=errors>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </td>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn"  value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
```

Everything renders perfectly in the template, except the dropdown for the foreign key the values listed over there are something like:

```
    <tr><label for="category">Category</label></tr>
     <tr><select id="category" name="category"><option selected value="__None"></option><option value="ahhkZXZ-bmV3LXByb2plY3QtdGVtcGxhdGVyEgsSDFRhc2tDYXRlZ29yeRgCDA">&lt;models.TaskCategory object at 0xb22d74c&gt;</option>

<option value="ahhkZXZ-bmV3LXByb2plY3QtdGVtcGxhdGVyEgsSDFRhc2tDYXRlZ29yeRgDDA">&lt;models.TaskCategory object at 0xb22dbec&gt;</option>

<option value="ahhkZXZ-bmV3LXByb2plY3QtdGVtcGxhdGVyFgsSDFRhc2tDYXRlZ29yeSIEdGVzdAw">&lt;models.TaskCategory object at 0xb22d74c&gt;</option></select></tr>
```

As is visible the names are not being displayed for the category, instead the objects are displayed, how can i rectify it, in a generic manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this has got nothing to do with, WTForm or jinja or webapp2. 
Change your database file to return the title in your case, instead of the object using `repr` as follows:

```
class TaskCategory(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
```