# Values in dropdown menu created using ReferencePropertyField() are not proper

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Flask on App Engine. Here is the code:

models.py:

```
class Client(db.Model):

    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

class Team(db.Model):

    name = db.StringProperty()
    member = db.ReferenceProperty(Client)
```

forms.py:

```
class TestForm(wtf.Form):

    name = wtf.TextField(description=u"Enter name")
    member = ReferencePropertyField(reference_class=Client)
```

views.py:

```
@app.route('/test_app/')
def test_app():

    form = TestForm()
    return render_template("test_app.html", form=form)
```

Template is rendering properly, but the value in the dropdown menu looks like this:

```
<select id="member" name="member"><option value="agxzfnRpY2stdHJhY2tyDAsSBkNsaWVudBgEDA">agxzfnRpY2stdHJhY2tyDAsSBkNsaWVudBgEDA</option></select>
```

There is also __repr__() defined under Client class in models.py, according to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168398/wtforms-display-foreignkey-fields-name-in-dropdown) it should work,but it is not working for me.

Comment: Please add the dropdown template code to your question.